# Use of paid RPC's

Tags: solana-program, rpc

Do you know if the Solana RPCs on the market have a difference in latency between the free and paid plans? And would you have any tips to reduce latency? I say this because I'm noticing a latency of at least 2 seconds when signing transactions in a free RPC that I'm using.

Comment: Unless you plan on doing a large volume of txs, in my experience the Solana official RPC is the one with the lowest latency.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the provider, there is a latency difference between free and paid plans. For example, [Quicknode](https://www.quicknode.com/) will provide faster endpoints for their Build plan vs the free tier. If you're looking to reduce latency, I'd recommend experimenting with different providers to see which one works the best for you. Generally Quicknode and [Helius](https://www.helius.dev/) are the best options (I use both in conjunction with [Ironforge](https://www.ironforge.cloud/)), and I'd try both and see if there's an improvement over the endpoint you're currently using. In general, average latency will vary depending on what RPC methods you're calling.

Comment: Disclosure: I work with QuickNode.

It also depends on the client's machine locations. Some providers might have better coverage in a particular region than others.